# Angular: binding to children of parent with contenteditable

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-template

I'm tried to make a paragraph with a couple of `span`s, where my content is. The reason of using `span` is that user can customize any part of paragraph with its own style.

But if I set `contenteditable` to parent, all children stop answering to events, such as `input`, `onkey`, etc.

If I set `contenteditable` to each `span` but remove it from parent, bindings to `span` works like a charm, but it doesn't allow to user make cross-span selection and editing.

So how can I set `contenteditable` to parent and save my bindings in spans? Or, if it impossible, how can I get child `span`, which user clicked and edit right now?

I hope, my question is clear. Below you can see my code, that not work as I expected.

Template:

```
<p contenteditable>
    <span *ngFor="let text of text_blocks" [innerText]="text.content" (input)="text.content=$event.target.innerText"></span>
</p>
```

Mock:

```
{
    "text_blocks" : [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "content" : "Lorem Ipsum"
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "content" : " is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. "
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "content" : "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to "
        },
        {
            "id" : 4,
            "content" : "a type specimen book. "
        },
        {
            "id" : 5,
            "content" : "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, "
        },
        {
            "id" : 6,
            "content" : "remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing "
        },
        {
            "id" : 7,
            "content" : "Lorem Ipsum"
        },
        {
            "id" : 8,
            "content" : " passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like"
        },
        {
            "id" : 9,
            "content" : " Aldus PageMaker "
        },
        {
            "id" : 10,
            "content" : "including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
        }
    ]
}
```